# Sitemaps при создании нового поста или новости

Tags: sitemap

здравствуйте, с генерировал sitemaps, всё ок но возник вопрос, как дальше быть, когда новый пост или новости появится, каждый раз по новому генерировать  или написать программу где при создание нового материала добавить в конец sitemaps.xml новый урл или как вы решаете этот вопрос?

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать, чтобы каждый раз пополнялся, а можно генерировать его "на ходу", включая самые важные ссылки. И кстати, вместо sitemap, насколько я знаю, можно просто использовать список ссылок, без xml мороки.

**UPDATE** Ну все тонкости не знаю, просто читал где-то в справке яндекса, что достаточно перечислить ссылки: по одной на строку. Не знаю, как правильно, но файл я всё равно называл Sitemap.xml. И вроде проблем ни с яндексом, ни с гуглом не было.
P.S. Прошу прощения, но через телефон не могу ответить в комментарии.

Comment: как это без xml, т.е. просто в txt файле через запятую? как назвать файл?

Comment: спасибо за инфо! +1